# Interpolate to velocity-position pair

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

For a (1-dimensional) physics simulation I am trying to program, I would like to interpolate from a certain initial position-velocity pair $y(0)=y_0$, $v(0)=v_0$ to a final position-velocity pair $y(T)=y_t$, $v(T)=v_t$, where $y'(T) = v(t)$. Preferably with some control over the time $T$ in which this interpolation takes time and no overshoot on y(t).

Are there any (systematic) procedures to find such a function $y(t, y_0, v_0, y_t, v_t)$ for which this holds? Note that $v(t)$ and $y(t)$ should be continuous on the domain $0\leq t\leq T$.

I already tried solving for the parameters of a critically damped spring-mass-damper system, a 3rd order polynomial or a combination of exponential functions, but I have difficulty solving this for all quadrants of the initial and final values.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Would I be correct in stating that the function would be the solution to the equation

$\mathbf x' = \begin{pmatrix}a & b\\c & d\end{pmatrix} \mathbf x\ -\begin{pmatrix} y_t \\ v_t\end{pmatrix}= \mathbf P \mathbf x\ -\mathbf Q$, where $\mathbf x=\begin{pmatrix} y \\ v\end{pmatrix}$

corresponding to the initial conditions $y(0)=y_0 , v(0)=v_0$, preferably with the matrix $\mathbf P=\begin{pmatrix}a & b\\c & d\end{pmatrix}$ having only one distinct eigenvalue?

Comment: This is easy enough to accomplish, *provided one knows something about the forces acting on the particle*. If there are no forces around, the solution is trivial: $y$ is linear and $v$ is constant. If there are forces acting on the particle. the path it takes will depend on those forces, so without knowing them, there is no way to determine the particle's path. Also, those forces and the initial conditions will uniquely determine the conditions at $T$, so you cannot have just any $y_t$ and $v_t$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair How can $v$ be constant if $v_t \neq v_0$? The initial conditions are as described in the question, namely $v_0$ and $y_0$. I think you are considering the problem from a more physical view than posed in my question. :) To elaborate on the physics of my question: All forces acting on the mass are described by the change in velocity $v'(t)=a(t)=\frac{F(t)}{m}$. My question should be interpreted as finding the force over time to apply to the mass to get from the initial conditions, $y_0, v_0$ to the final conditions $y_t, v_t$.

Comment: If there is no information about the forces involved, then your problem is underspecified. In fact, massively underspecified. There infinitely many - uncountably infinitely many - paths that will meet all your conditions. And there is no hint of how to choose between them. Which path do you want?

Comment: Any path, maybe the simplest. Preferably one with control over the time $T$ it takes until the final conditions are reached and with no overshoot on y(t).

Comment: @PaulSinclair I have edited the question slightly to update my own investigations. As far as I understand, solving this system would result in solutions that move linearly to the final conditions in the $y, v$ plane. Please correct me if I am wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution doesn't work because it overlooks a key point: $v$ is the derivative of $y$ with respect to $t$. You solution does not obey this.

Your path has to depend on 4 known parameters: $y(0) = y_0, y'(0) = v_0, y(T) = y_t, y'(t) = v_t$. So you need 4 degrees of freedom to match them.

The simplest function that has 4 independent parameters is a cubic. So I suggest using:
$$y(t) = at^3 + bt^2 + ct + d$$
for appropriate values of $a, b, c, d$.

As described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_Hermite_spline#Interpolation_on_a_single_interval), $y$ is given by [edit: corrected for the error Mark Marketing points out below]
$$y(t) = \left(2\left[\frac tT\right]^3 - 3\left[\frac tT\right]^2 + 1\right)y_0 + \left(\left[\frac tT\right]^3 - 2\left[\frac tT\right]^2 + \left[\frac tT\right]\right)Tv_0 \\+ \left(3\left[\frac tT\right]^2 - 2\left[\frac tT\right]^3\right)y_t + \left(\left[\frac tT\right]^3 - \left[\frac tT\right]^2\right)Tv_t$$

Comment: Thank you so much! I edited your answer a bit as you forgot to multiply the values $v_0$ and $v_t$ with T so the speed was scaled incorrectly. I can't believe I didn't consider spline interpolation yet. I found the problem while making a small demo to verify your formula: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/zqu3zz0rcw

Comment: @Mark Marketing - The problem is that I was too cavalier in scaling for $T$. I see that someone rejected your edit, but I'll fix later when I have more time.

Comment: No problem, I followed the wikipedia page and it works perfectly

Comment: By the way, I noticed that for $T=3, v_0=v_t=0$, this formula approximates a sine wave quite well on the interval $0\leq t \leq T$, with an error of at most .02. which is interesting; https://www.desmos.com/calculator/q6min85j8l

Comment: @MarkMarketing - That is because the polynomial is the 3rd-order Taylor polynomial of the sinusoid about $t = T/2$, If you were to choose any other analytic function $f$, and set $y_0$, etc, to the values of $f$ and $f'$ at $0$ and $T$, then I suspect you would also find that this method would give it's cubic Taylor polynomial about $t = T/2$ as well.